# Notificações iguais as do facebook para PHP

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent

Qual o melhor caminho para se desenvolver notificações que funcionem iguais as do facebook quando alguém curte alguma postagem? Estou utilizando PHP & Laravel 5.5. Alguém sabe ou já viu isso em Angular/VueJS/Javascript?

Comment: Procure por Sockets TCP, nenhuma framework ai serve para isso

Comment: Se você querer utilizar alguma ferramente pra te ajudar com isso, você pode utilizar o Pusher que o Laravel indica ou o Socket.IO